# How to use jquery-addresspicker jquery with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-address

I am trying to use jquery-addresspicker with rails 3.1 but I am not able to make it run.

Here is the link https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker and the documentation does not mention much.

Can anyone suggest how should I use it in my rails app?

Comment: you have the demo html inside, it says nothing about rails 3.1 but it is easy as long as you include the script, give the right id's to the text_fields and so on.. +1 for finding the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you include google maps

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

and jquery-ui ?

Comment: If I do inspect element I can see that both these files are included

Comment: Check out JS include order. you must include google map before addresspicker otherwise you'll get a JS error: google is undefined

Answer (score 1):

place the script code in the html, or in separate js file

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var addresspicker = $( "#addresspicker" ).addresspicker();
            var addresspickerMap = $( "#addresspicker_map" ).addresspicker({
                regionBias: "fr",
              elements: {
                map:      "#map",
                lat:      "#lat",
                lng:      "#lng",
                locality: '#locality',
                country:  '#country'
              }
            });
            var gmarker = addresspickerMap.addresspicker( "marker");
            gmarker.setVisible(true);
            addresspickerMap.addresspicker( "updatePosition");

        });
    </script>


<div>
    <div class='input'>
      <%= f.label :address %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :address, :id => "addresspicker_map" %>
      <%= f.label :locality %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :locality, :id => "locality", :disabled => "true" %>
      <%= f.label :country %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :country, :id => "country", :disabled => "true" %>
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="legend">You can drag and drop the marker to the correct location</div>
  </div>
```

this is a piece of  tutorial I made. I haven't tried it, but this is a start for you.
you'll have to style it with css from here:

https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker/blob/master/demos/demo.css

include the js file in the app from here:

https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker/tree/master/src

and images:

https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker/tree/master/demos/images

Comment: its not working, I have tried exactly how you have written but it does not autocomplete the location and the map does not come up either

Comment: I am looking into it. the autocomplete is included in the jquery.ui.addresspicker.js so there is no need to include any other plugin for this

Comment: thanks a ton by the way I have pushed the app on heroku as well in case you want to have a look, I have made the location and country field hidden so they do not show up on the page. Here is the link http://quiet-ice-5806.heroku.com/

Comment: ok. I'll look into it.. but for start, you have no JS files included as the demo requires

Comment: thanks for your help got it working by changing the order of google maps js

Comment: Hey, the autocomplete fields are working, but when I try the demo the map isn't displaying.. what do you think I'm doing wrong? Running rails app as well. Thanks!

Comment: first thing I am thinking of is to look at the demo source code and see how the elements are loaded.. I remember putting the <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> at the end of the <head> tag and I had no map displayed. Make sure the js files loads in the same order as in the demo http://xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html

Comment: anyway, I can assure you that I tried to use this plugin in my rails app and it's working very nice.

Answer (score 0):

This has been ported to rails here at this repo https://github.com/ddidier/address_picker-rails