# How to use jquery-addresspicker in rails 4.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Anyone know how to use it? 
I have tried but still fail
and in my sources console I get this error 
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

I put the jquery.ui.addresspicker.js in my vendor/assets/javascripts folder 
here is my
application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker 
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require jquery.ui.addresspicker
//= require_tree .
```

And I have include googlemaps in my application.html.slim

```
head
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"
```

I have found the gem but it's not support rails 4
https://github.com/ddidier/address_picker-rails

and here is similar questions but that questions still not show me how to use the jquery-adresspicker
[How to use jquery-addresspicker jquery with rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393793/how-to-use-jquery-addresspicker-jquery-with-rails-3-1)

*update*
I try to change the order of script in my application.html.slim
and put the googlemaps script first
and now I get this error

Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have make it work by using bower-rails
https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails/

after the installation via bower-rails 
call the required js to rails asset pipeline (application.js) 
my application.js

```
...
//= require typeahead.js/dist/bloodhound.js
//= require typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.jquery.js
//= require typeahead-addresspicker/dist/typeahead-addresspicker.js
//= require_tree .
```

the rest is just like when u implement it in plain html file

and if you following the sample code from readme.md and the map is not shown, don't forget to add this to your css file
I put it in my Model.scss file

```
#map {
  float:right;
  width: 490px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another gem for this JS library: [typeahead-addresspicker-rails](https://github.com/ivaravko/typeahead-addresspicker-rails). Based on the rubygem specs, it looks like it supports Rails 4.

Comment: ah yeah I know that one but somehow I still can't implement it, thats why I try to use non typehead one because it looks like way simpler.